# Simultaneously deminiaturize an array of NSWindows programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, macos, cocoa, nswindow

In Cocoa (Objective-C) how can you programmatically simultaneously deminiaturize a group of NSWindow instances *without* using a background thread?

If you call 'deminiaturize:' on an NSWindow instance it will block the main thread for the duration of the deminiaturization process (about 0.3 seconds). If you instruct an array of windows to deminiaturize they will do so one at a time, cumulatively taking quite a while, all the time blocking the main thread. The desired affect can be achieved using a background thread but this (rightly) throws console log errors.

The ability to safely deminiaturize a group of 5+ windows in 0.3 seconds or less would be ideal. Is there a way to remove the animation from the deminiaturization in order to speed up the process? Is there another way to restore windows to the screen without calling 'deminiaturize:'?

Comment: The dock is doing the deminiaturization. The Scale effect is faster. Press the shift key for slow motion.

Comment: `close` won't release the window if `releasedWhenClosed` is false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using a combination of `setReleasedWhenClosed:`, `close`, and  `makeKeyAndOrderFront:`, it is possible to effectively deminiaturize an array of NSWindows without any animation (i.e. instantly) - and without actually deallocating the objects.

Objective-C:

```
void deminiaturizeWindowsWithoutAnimation(NSArray<NSWindow *> *windows) {
    for (NSWindow * window in windows) {
        if ([window isMiniaturized]) {
            BOOL old_isReleasedWhenClosed = [window isReleasedWhenClosed];
            [window setReleasedWhenClosed:false];
            [window close];
            [window makeKeyAndOrderFront: nil];
            [window setReleasedWhenClosed:old_isReleasedWhenClosed];
        }
    }
}
```

Swift:

```
func deminiaturizeWithoutAnimation(windows: [NSWindow]) {
    for window in windows {
        guard window.isMiniaturized else { continue }
        let old_isReleasedWhenClosed = window.isReleasedWhenClosed
        window.isReleasedWhenClosed = false
        window.close()
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
        window.isReleasedWhenClosed = old_isReleasedWhenClosed
    }
}
```

These functions can be called from the main thread. Tested on macOS Sierra.

If you'd like, you can replace `makeKeyAndOrderFront:` with `orderFront:` or `orderBack:` to avoid changing the key window. (Although makeKeyAndOrderFront's behavior replicates that of `deminiaturize:`, which results in the window becoming the key window.)

Comment: This is a great answer. I did have to save and re-establish the the window controller and window delegate, as well as intercept the NSWindowWillCloseNotification, for some types of windows too (those essentially created / retained by only a storyboard). Also, the new tabbed windows in macOS 10.12 ungroup using this solution... but all in all it does what I require so thanks for that!

Comment: Great points. Digging into how `deminiaturize:` works led to a bunch of private internals of NSWindow and the private CoreDock framework. It's much easier to just use this trick to get rid of the window in the dock and then re-display it, than to try method swizzling the internal NSWindows selectors or using that private framework (which also would not be Mac App Store-compatible and likely break in a future OS release - this method is considerably safer).